# WebStorm 8, install grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, gruntjs, webstorm

Can't install Grunt package in WebStorm 8:
`Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package grunt.`

Log:

```
Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package grunt. 
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install grunt

Exit code: 1
```

Standard error:

```
npm ERR! Error: Invalid version: "0.1"
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixVersionField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:183:13)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:30:38
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at normalize (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:29:15)
npm ERR!     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:342:33)
npm ERR!     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:126:33)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:328:57
npm ERR!     at fs.js:207:20
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.Req.done (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:144:5)
npm ERR!     at OpenReq.done (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:64:22)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\ID25\Desktop\untitled1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm`
```

please, help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your package.json - what is the "version" value? '0.1' is not a valid value, as it doesn't conform to the versioning scheme (http://semver.org/) npm packages uses. see https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html